# Powershell script not running via Task Schedular

Tags: powershell

I have the following script written and saved via PowerShell.

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://10.39.60.23:8085/home/index -Method GET
```

In the Task Scheduler within Action under Program/Script I have the following string

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Lastly under Add Argument I have the following

```
C:\TSC.ps1
```

which is the location of the script.
Unfortunately the script does not return the data I expect it to.

Comment: No changes, this is the message displayed under "Last Run Result" 0XFFFD0000

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way out.
I had not changed the execution policy. So I ran the following command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Then with the same parameters in check under the Task Scheduler, it was able to run successfully.